# Не подключается сертификат к telegram

Tags: php, бот, telegram

Пытаюсь подключить сертификат к телеграм.

Создал сертификат командой:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout ИМЯ.key
-x509 -days 365 -out ИМЯ.pem -subj
"/C=RU/ST=КРАЙ/L=ГОРОД/0=ПОДРАЗДЕЛЕНИЕ/CN=МОЙСАЙТ"
```

Ключ создался. На выходе получил:

```
ИМЯ.key
ИМЯ.pem
```

Далее - в настройках сайта (использую ISPmanager) добавил свой сертификат. Привязал его к сайту, который указывал при создании сертификата. Всё прошло успешно.

Далее. Воспользовался командой:

```
curl -F "url=https://МОЙСАЙТ/bot.php"
-F "certificate=ИМЯ.pem"
"https://api.telegram.org/botТОКЕНМОЕГОБОТА/setwebhook"
```

В ответ пришло сообщение:

> {"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}

Вроде как ключ установился (если я правильно понял).
Вписываю в браузере строку:

```
https://api.telegram.org/botТОКЕНМОЕГОБОТА/getWebhookInfo
```

Возвращает такой результат:

> {"ok":true,"result":{"url":"[https://МОЙСАЙТ/bot.php](https://%D0%9C%D0%9E%D0%99%D0%A1%D0%90%D0%99%D0%A2/bot.php)","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":7,"max_connections":40}}

Меня напрягает это:

> "has_custom_certificate":false

Мой сертификат получается не самоподписной? (Или что???)

Ну собственно, мой скрипт обработки bot.php:

```
<?php

$updates = file_get_contents("php://input");
$updates = json_decode($updates, true);

$chatID = $updates["message"]["chat"]["id"];
$text = $updates["message"]["text"];

sendMessage($chatID, $text);

function sendMessage($chatID, $message)
{
    $url = $GLOBALS[website]."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=".urldecode($message);
    file_get_contents($url);
}
```

Пишу своему боту - в ответ тишина. Получается, вебхук не срабатывает.
Что не так сделано?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы Telegram мог отсылать данные по ссылкам, где установлен самоподписанный сертификат, нужно методом setWebhook передавать вместе со ссылкой сам сертификат (параметр certificate, формат inputFile).
Почитать про сертификаты можно здесь:
self-signed cert guide: https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52352/discussion-on-answer-by-evgenii-bogdanov-----telegram).

Answer (score 0):

согласно [How do I set a webhook for either type](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks#how-do-i-set-a-webhook-for-either-type) если сертификат самоподписной перед его именем ставим **@**, т.о. получается

```
curl -F "url=https://МОЙСАЙТ/bot.php" -F "certificate=@ИМЯ.pem" "https://api.telegram.org/botТОКЕНМОЕГОБОТА/setwebhook"
```